# Training yields very low error but very incorrect (almost all ones) output

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to train an autoencoder on some simulated data where an input is basically a vector with Gaussian noise applied. The code is almost exactly the same as in this example: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/autoencoder.py

The only differences are I changed the network parameters and the cost function:

```
    n_hidden_1 = 32 # 1st layer num features
    n_hidden_2 = 16 # 2nd layer num features
    n_input = 149 # LunaH-Map data input (number of counts per orbit)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_true * tf.log(y_pred), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

During training, the error steadily decreases down to 0.00015, but the predicted and true values are very different, e.g.
[as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1CNd.png). In fact, the predicted y vector is almost all ones.

How is it possible to get decreasing error with very wrong predictions? Is it possible that my network is just trying to move the weights closer to log(1) so as to minimize the cross entropy cost? If so, how do I combat this?

Comment: What data do you use for evaluation? training data, or unused validation data?

Comment: If that prediction you showed is on unseen data, you might be running into the problem of overfitting, i.e. your algorithm just "memorizes" the training dataset but does not generalize well enough to new, unseen data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the network simply learns to to predict `1` which reduces the loss. The cross-entropy loss you are using is categorical which is used when `y_true` is one-hot code (example: [0,0,1,0]) and final layer is `softmax` (ensures sum of all output is 1). So when y_true[idx] is 0, the loss don't care while when the y_true[idx] is 1 and y_pred[idx] is 0 there is infinite(high) loss but if its 1 then loss is again 0.

Now categorical cross-entropy loss is not suitable for autoencoders. For real valued inputs and hence outputs its mean-squared-error, which is what is used in example that you cited. But there the final activation layer is `sigmoid`, implicitly saying that each element of `x` is 0/1. So either you need to convert your data to support the same or have the last layer of decoder linear.

If you do want to use cross-entropy loss you can use binary cross-entropy 
For inputs with 0,1 binary cross-entropy:  `tf.reduce_mean(y_true * tf.log(y_pred) + (1-y_true) * tf.log(1-y_pred))`. If you work it out in both misprediction case 0-1, 1-0, the network gets infinite loss. Note again here the final layer should be `softmax` and elements of `x` should be between 0 and 1